# Google Cloud Compute / Unexpected Sizing Recommendations

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cpu-usage, gcloud

[image]

The issue's in the picture; while the instance stays below 10% of cpu use, I still see gcloud recommending to increase the CPU

Does such recommandation not only relies on cpu use ? What other metrics should be taken into account to understand why such an alert appear ?

Comment: How much RAM are you using? From the screen, I can see your VM has 1.7 Gb and Google is recommending one more Giga.

Comment: yep. but does it really matters ? the cpu chart is the one of the instance showing this alert

Comment: it depends; if your application saturates the RAM, yes, it matters. The notification also says that the INSTANCE is overutilized, not the CPU only

Comment: where/how one could inspect such metrics ?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/941959/22050 which roughly shows the following : `CPU 1.9% RAM 27.4% HDD 24%` just installed the stackdriver monitoring agent (https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent), which returns a corresponding memory usage (around 25%)

Comment: It is actually recommending to increase RAM and leave the CPU the same at 1 vCPU. What does your RAM usage graph look like?

Comment: @OliverAragon I might miss the point maybe; am sorry bu what metrics is considered as RAM ? Stackdriver does not provide a graph for "ram", however, as said above, the stackdriver agent once installed provide a value for memory usage. CPU is extremely low (around 2%), and memory usage is expected (around 25%). What metrics should be taken into account to understand why google is alerting ?

Comment: @OliverAragon launched another instance yesterday,  simply running nginx, serving static files, and receiving less a thousand hits a day. And today am getting the same alert on this machine

Comment: I was checking the [documents](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/apply-sizing-recommendations-for-instances#viewing_sizing_recommendations) and it looks like you can turn off recommendations if you want. It also says that they use 8 days of historical data to make recommendations. You can also submit a [support ticket](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/free_trial_support) so they can look at your project and let you know why the recommandation might be there in the first place